What is smallest non-rectangle scalene triangle with integer sides and heights?
So far I've found out that given any triangle with integer side lengths and rational area, then the heights must also be rational. Then, just just multiply the side lengths and heights by the least common multiple of the denominators and everything is an integer. However, every time I find a triangle, i always manage to find a smaller one. Could anyone help me find this triangle and prove that it is the smallest? By smallest, I mean perimeter. However, it would be interesting if a triangle has a smaller perimeter and another has a smaller area.
Update: I wrote a python code (which I removed because people seemed to focus more on the program than the mathematical question itself) to find the answer. It gave me triangle with side lengths (35, 75, 100) as the smallest triangle. Is there a proof that it is the smallest?

For what it's worth, I created an answer and then deleted it because someone provided a comment that convinced me that my analysis was invalid.  I overlooked the constraint in the title that the heights must also be integers.

The 13-14-15 triangle has altitude 12 to side 14, You can work out the scale factor to make the other altitudes integral. I haven't worked it out so don't know whether it's better than what you found.

How could your answer possibly be incorrect? Your code is calculating every possibility.

@Snared It seems to me that the real challenge of the problem is to find an analytical, rather than programmatic solution.

As a crude starting point, suppose that the sides are $~a,b,c \in \Bbb{Z^+}~$ such that $~a < b < c,~$ such that $~\displaystyle S = \frac{a + b + c}{2},~$ and such that $~\displaystyle T = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s - c)}.~$ Then, by Heron's formula, $~T~$ equals the area of the triangle.  Now let the heights be represented by $~d,e,f \in \Bbb{Z^+}.~$ Then, you can specify that $$2T = ad = be = cf.$$  I don't see how this solves the problem, but this would certainly be my first try.

@EthanBolker That is obtained by joining a $5/12/13$ triangle to a $9/12/15$ triangle (both right-angled) along the common edge. The $35/75/100$ one is $21/28/35$ (modelled on $3/4/5 \times 7$) with $21/72/75 (= 7/24/25 \times 3)$.  I think it should be possible to show that all solutions can be obtained in this way.

The 'is_integer' function is fallible. Try ((1/49)*49).is_integer() and (1 + 10**-16).is_integer(). You must avoid using floating-point numbers.

@MarkBennet I knew that construction. The 13-14-15 triangle was a favorite in math competitions in New York City in the 1950s (today's high school problems would be much harder). I too think you get all the solutions this way.

@mr_e_man Better to verify that s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c) is a perfect square, and that a divides 2s directly by using factor() functionality. For these miniscule numbers we're checking, even the trivial factor implantation where you iterate between $1$ and $\sqrt {2s}$ produces the answer basically instantly. Keep in mind we're sorting the set of scalene triangles by perimeter and so long as every triangle of perimeter $p$ or smaller with the desired property has been checked, you know you don't need to check any more scalene triangles with perimeter $p+1$ or larger.

@mr_e_man Thanks for the advise. However, this is more of a math question than a programming one. The python code was just here to help me find an answer, but what I'm truly looking for is a mathematical explanation. Thanks!

FWIW, the 13-14-15 triangle with one altitude equal to 12 would have to be scaled up by 65 to get all three altitudes integral (thus 845-910-975 with corresponding altitudes 840-780-728).

I can propose the following semianalytic solution.
Multiplying the sides of the required triangle by $2$, if needed, we suppose that at least one side of the triangle has even length. Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be the sides of the required triangle, $h_a$, $h_b$, and $h_c$ be the respective altitudes, and $A$ be the area of the triangle. Then $2A=ah_a=bh_b=ch_c$, so
the triangle is Heronian and we have to check scalene non-right-angled Heronian triangles.
For this purpose we use the following method
to generate all Heronian triangles discovered by Leonhard Euler, who was the first to provably parametrize all such triangles.
For four positive integers $m$ coprime to $n$ and $p$ coprime to $q$ satisfying $mp>nq$ (to guarantee positive side lengths) we put $a=mn(p^{2}+q^{2})$, $b=pq(m^{2}+n^{2})$, and $c=(mq+np)(mp-nq)$.
Then $A=mnpq(mq+np)(mp-nq)$ and the semiperimeter $s$ of the triangle equals $mp(mq + np)$.
The altitudes of the triangle are integer iff $2(mq+np)(mp-nq)$ is divisible both by $p^{2}+q^{2}$ and $m^2+n^2$. The latter condition holds iff $(p^2+q^2)|2((m^2-n^2)q+2mnp)$ and $(m^2+n^2)|2((p^2-q^2)n+2mpq)$.
A simple computer program shows that in the range of $m,n,p,q$ from $1$ to $20$ there are the following solutions:
 m=1 n=2 p=7 q=1 a=100 b=35 c=75 s=105 A=1050
 m=2 n=3 p=17 q=7 a=2028 b=1547 c=845 s=2210 A=603330
 m=3 n=1 p=7 q=1 a=150 b=70 c=200 s=210 A=4200
 m=3 n=4 p=11 q=2 a=1500 b=550 c=1250 s=1650 A=330000
 m=4 n=3 p=13 q=9 a=3000 b=2925 c=1875 s=3900 A=2632500
 m=4 n=7 p=18 q=1 a=9100 b=1170 c=8450 s=9360 A=4258800
 m=5 n=1 p=17 q=7 a=1690 b=3094 c=4056 s=4420 A=2413320
 m=7 n=1 p=1 q=2 a=35 b=100 c=75 s=105 A=1050
 m=7 n=1 p=3 q=1 a=70 b=150 c=200 s=210 A=4200
 m=7 n=1 p=9 q=13 a=1750 b=5850 c=5000 s=6300 A=4095000
 m=7 n=1 p=11 q=2 a=875 b=1100 c=1875 s=1925 A=288750
 m=7 n=4 p=19 q=17 a=18200 b=20995 c=12675 s=25935 A=114632700
 m=7 n=6 p=19 q=8 a=17850 b=12920 c=14450 s=22610 A=92248800
 m=7 n=9 p=17 q=6 a=20475 b=13260 c=12675 s=23205 A=81449550
 m=8 n=1 p=17 q=6 a=2600 b=6630 c=8450 s=8840 A=6895200
 m=8 n=19 p=13 q=1 a=25840 b=5525 c=21675 s=26520 A=42829800
 m=9 n=2 p=13 q=16 a=7650 b=17680 c=14450 s=19890 A=54100800
 m=9 n=13 p=7 q=1 a=5850 b=1750 c=5000 s=6300 A=4095000
 m=11 n=2 p=3 q=4 a=550 b=1500 c=1250 s=1650 A=330000
 m=11 n=2 p=7 q=1 a=1100 b=875 c=1875 s=1925 A=288750
 m=11 n=3 p=17 q=19 a=21450 b=41990 c=33800 s=48620 A=360274200
 m=11 n=3 p=18 q=1 a=10725 b=2340 c=12675 s=12870 A=7528950
 m=11 n=7 p=16 q=13 a=32725 b=35360 c=21675 s=44880 A=347146800
 m=13 n=1 p=8 q=19 a=5525 b=25840 c=21675 s=26520 A=42829800
 m=13 n=9 p=4 q=3 a=2925 b=3000 c=1875 s=3900 A=2632500
 m=13 n=16 p=9 q=2 a=17680 b=7650 c=14450 s=19890 A=54100800
 m=16 n=13 p=11 q=7 a=35360 b=32725 c=21675 s=44880 A=347146800
 m=17 n=6 p=7 q=9 a=13260 b=20475 c=12675 s=23205 A=81449550
 m=17 n=6 p=8 q=1 a=6630 b=2600 c=8450 s=8840 A=6895200
 m=17 n=7 p=2 q=3 a=1547 b=2028 c=845 s=2210 A=603330
 m=17 n=7 p=5 q=1 a=3094 b=1690 c=4056 s=4420 A=2413320
 m=17 n=19 p=11 q=3 a=41990 b=21450 c=33800 s=48620 A=360274200
 m=18 n=1 p=4 q=7 a=1170 b=9100 c=8450 s=9360 A=4258800
 m=18 n=1 p=11 q=3 a=2340 b=10725 c=12675 s=12870 A=7528950
 m=19 n=8 p=7 q=6 a=12920 b=17850 c=14450 s=22610 A=92248800
 m=19 n=17 p=7 q=4 a=20995 b=18200 c=12675 s=25935 A=114632700

We see that the solution $(a,b,c)=(100,35,75)$ is the first and corresponds to $(m,n,p,q)=(1,2,7,1)$, so it can be easily found by hand. In this case we have $s=105$ and $A=1050$. It is easy to show that the solutions nonlisted above provide required triangles with bigger both semiperimeter and area.
